# Reconstruct version control from set of files

Tags: database, git, algorithm, version, controls

I am looking after an approach for the following task:

given a set of files that are highly similar (I am using Fuzzy hashing here), I would like to know if there is an algorithm that allows to label those files with a version number. The output should return the sequential order of when those files have been generated.

The reason is I have to re-organize data of a team who were not familiar with version control.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple approach (I hope) would be to try and convert this into some kind of graph problem.

Let's say every file is a node with edges between every two files.
The weight of an edge between two nodes would be, for instance, the number of different lines between the files (or some some other function).

What you do next is find a non-cyclic path that traverses all files with the minimum cost. something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), if you know the first file and the last.
You could add an empty file and the latest version you have as your *start* and *end* nodes.

I'm guessing this won't give you the exact result, but it'll probably give you a good starting point.
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you. sounds interesting !